# I Am Having Trouble Getting This Loop To Work Can Anyone Help Me?

Tags: python

**can anyone understand why this wont reset if answered incorrectly?**

```
def loop1:
(print) ("Please Enter Your Name.")
myName = input(:)
(print) ("Hello " +myName)
(print) ("Would You Kindly Confirm If the Hatch Is Open Or Closed O/C") 
hacthStatus = input ()
if hacthStatus == ('C'):
    loop1()
```

Comment: Please elaborate your problem statement with  expected behavior explained.

Answer (score 1):

your code has no indentation and also you have not defined function properly

try this

```
def loop1():  
      print ("Please Enter Your Name.")
      myName = input(":")
      print ("Hello " +myName)
      print ("Would You Kindly Confirm If the Hatch Is Open Or Closed O/C") 
      hacthStatus = input ()
      if hacthStatus == 'C':
          loop1()

loop1()
```

the above code is equivalent to

```
hacthStatus = 'C'
while  hacthStatus == 'C':
      print ("Please Enter Your Name.")
      myName = input(":")
      print ("Hello " +myName)
      hacthStatus = input ("Would You Kindly Confirm If the Hatch Is Open Or Closed O/C\n")
```

Comment: that just makes a never ending instant loop

Comment: If you type Value other than `C` it ends otherwise it will be infinite as long as you give `hacthStatus` value as `C`, Your problem statement is not clear

Comment: the second i boot it just restarts